# Ajax POST requests to Heroku loses post data

Tags: ajax, heroku

My ajax post requests to my Heroku app loses its post data in approximately 90% of the calls.

I was using GET and changed to POST for security reasons. The GET requests have been working for months. The POST requests work like a charm locally in the IDE and using foreman. But when moving it to my Heroku app the POST data is lost in 90% of the calls.

I am pretty sure that the data is sent correctly as:

1. It works when running my application locally
2. Using Chrome dev tools I verify that the data is part of the call

I dump detailed incoming request data to the Papertrail logs. Here I can see that the data is gone. The content-length indicates that the request data should be there, but it is just gone.

The Ajax call I am using. I have tried with $.post request and non-jquery ajax request. I have tried with JSON.stringify on the data and many many different combinations of request headers.

```
 function doPostRequestWithDataV2(method, data) {
    var methodName = "/call/echo";
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url: methodName,
        data: {uuuuu: "ppppp"},
    })
            .done(function () {
                var jsonString = jqxhr.responseText;
                alert("All went well: " + jsonString);
            })
            .error(function () {
                alert("Problem: " + jqxhr.responseText);
            });
}
```

Full output successful call. The important differences in bold.

```
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: FIRST TOUCH: Number of bytes 945
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: FIRST TOUCH: ##########
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: POST /call/echo HTTP/1.1
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: Host: staging.kollektivafondval.se
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: Connection: close
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: Accept: */*
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: Referer: http://staging.kollektivafondval.se/debug/index.html
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.492366677.1421911589; __utma=33200548.492366677.1421911589.1425495130.1425495130.1; __utmc=33200548; __utmz=33200548.1425495130.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); cp=0; undefined=0; ptl=0; _gat=1
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: Pragma: no-cache
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: Cache-Control: no-cache
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: X-Request-Id: 17981145-acce-49bf-a5dd-e212a2a184ef
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: X-Forwarded-For: 83.227.55.31
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: X-Forwarded-Proto: http
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: X-Forwarded-Port: 80
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: Via: 1.1 vegur
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: Connect-Time: 0
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: X-Request-Start: 1425709758119
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: Total-Route-Time: 0
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: Content-Length: 17
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: String=any+string
Mar 07 07:29:18 my-fine-app app/web.1: ##########
```

Full output when data is missing. The important differences in bold.

```
Mar 07 07:29:15 my-fine-app app/web.1: ************************************************************
Mar 07 07:29:16 my-fine-app app/web.1: FIRST TOUCH: Number of bytes 928
Mar 07 07:29:16 my-fine-app app/web.1: FIRST TOUCH: ##########
Mar 07 07:29:16 my-fine-app app/web.1: POST /call/echo HTTP/1.1
Mar 07 07:29:16 my-fine-app app/web.1: Host: staging.kollektivafondval.se
Mar 07 07:29:16 my-fine-app app/web.1: Connection: close
Mar 07 07:29:16 my-fine-app app/web.1: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0
Mar 07 07:29:16 my-fine-app app/web.1: Accept: */*
Mar 07 07:29:16 my-fine-app app/web.1: Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Mar 07 07:29:16 my-fine-app app/web.1: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Mar 07 07:29:16 my-fine-app app/web.1: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Mar 07 07:29:16 my-fine-app app/web.1: X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Mar 07 07:29:16 my-fine-app app/web.1: Referer: http://staging.kollektivafondval.se/debug/index.html
Mar 07 07:29:16 my-fine-app app/web.1: Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.492366677.1421911589; __utma=33200548.492366677.1421911589.1425495130.1425495130.1; __utmc=33200548; __utmz=33200548.1425495130.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); cp=0; undefined=0; ptl=0; _gat=1
Mar 07 07:29:16 my-fine-app app/web.1: Pragma: no-cache
Mar 07 07:29:16 my-fine-app app/web.1: Cache-Control: no-cache
Mar 07 07:29:16 my-fine-app app/web.1: X-Request-Id: 16caf2b0-88a6-455b-ac03-71581920e1e5
Mar 07 07:29:16 my-fine-app app/web.1: X-Forwarded-For: 83.227.55.31
Mar 07 07:29:16 my-fine-app app/web.1: X-Forwarded-Proto: http
Mar 07 07:29:16 my-fine-app app/web.1: X-Forwarded-Port: 80
Mar 07 07:29:16 my-fine-app app/web.1: Via: 1.1 vegur
Mar 07 07:29:16 my-fine-app app/web.1: Connect-Time: 0
Mar 07 07:29:16 my-fine-app app/web.1: X-Request-Start: 1425709756264
Mar 07 07:29:16 my-fine-app app/web.1: Total-Route-Time: 0
Mar 07 07:29:16 my-fine-app app/web.1: Content-Length: 17
Mar 07 07:29:16 my-fine-app app/web.1: ##########
```

Comment: what stack are you using? Probably if you use any high level framework, the csrf (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) protection is can cause this, because it is usually applied to POST requests

Comment: I am using a proprietary web server written in Java. The output in the log is the result of a socket read without any processing, save converting the bytes to a String. Given this, do you think CSRF could still be the cause? I am pretty sure the browser is not limiting what is sent to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ehh. I found the answer to my own question. I turns out that Heroku's routing layer does a pause after sending the header. So all I had to do is to add a 2 millisecond sleep after all the bytes have been read and then do another read from the socket. Now it works perfectly.